# How can I open websites on my laptop which I can open in my mobile using the same WIFI?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, internet-connection

I have recently moved to a new shared accommodation where one WIFI is available for my use. I can open every website in my android mobile but I can't open most websites on my Windows 10 laptop. I don't have any problem when I use my mobile data hoptspot.

Specific problem- I can't open most websites like bbc.co.uk using this particular WIFI.

I want to open the websites that I can't open using the WIFI.

Please give suggestions how I can solve this problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you open the website on your Android device are you connected via WLAN or via mobile internet?

Comment: An improperly configured router or Internet provider might be blocking DNS. See if setting the DNS to 1.1.1.1 (cloudflare) or 8.8.8.8 (google) might fix it? https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-your-pcs-dns-settings-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely with the setting of the Wi-Fi router to which
you connect.

You should contact the person that controls the router - he might have
set a too strong security that blocks your access, for example a
by setting a MAC filter.